# How to check data values for validation in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have "state" column in "Todo" model, which must one of the following strings: "new", "in progress" or "finished". How can I implement this in `todo.rb` file with validation?

Comment: Why don't you use [`enum`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#enums)?

Comment: Is it a string in database? If the choices are limited, and this is a new model, it's better to store as `integer` ... as it currently stands, your question is vague; a code sample of your model would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an [inclusion validation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#inclusion) for this:

```
validates :state, inclusion: { in: ['new', 'in progress', 'finished'] }
```

However like [Marek Lipka already suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60928500/how-to-check-data-values-for-validation-in-activerecord#comment107794336_60928500), using [enums](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#enums) might be better suited in this scenario.